# Laravel5 Redirect to external URL with params

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5

I've gone through the following page, but I can't find any examples at all: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirects.

I've tried the following:

`return redirect()->away('http://bla.com');`

This works, but as soon as you add params to it you get the following error message

**PHP:**

`return redirect()->away('http://bla.com', ['bla' => 'bla']);`

**ERROR:**

`InvalidArgumentException in Response.php line 470:
The HTTP status code "1" is not valid.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add them to the string.

```
return redirect()->away('http://bla.com?bla=bla');
```

The second parameter for this function is the http status that should be sent to the visitor. So when you add an array this is parsed as a `1`.

Comment: Not a very Laravel-esque solution compared to the other examples they had, but I'll take it. Thanks man! **edit:** by 'not very laravel-esque' I mean it doesn't have the same input for passing params in an array from the same function like the others (hope that makes sense)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get some variable ,you can use this

```
$kw='bla';
return redirect()->away('http://bla.com?bla='.$kw);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I didn't find anything better than the following code;

```php
 $url = $redirectUrl . '?' . http_build_query($array);
 return Redirect::away($url);
```