# Redirect to external url with GET Parameter in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there possibility to redirect user to an external URL and pass paramter to it i Laravel 5?

Comment: Have you done any research? When I Google `Redirect to external url with GET Parameter in Laravel 5` there seem to be useful results, are they not helpful?

Comment: 5 minutes after asking question, I found solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34390850/laravel5-redirect-to-external-url-with-params)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`away()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.html#method_away) method:

```
return redirect()->away('http://sample.com/url?param=param')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values to views:

```
Route::get('/user/{id}', function () {
   $user = User::find($id);
   return view('user', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

And then access user in the view:

```
{{ $user }}
```